# 'SELECT IN' with item list containing duplicates

Tags: sql, t-sql, select

I'm doing

```
SELECT Name WHERE Id IN (3,4,5,3,7,8,9)
```

where in this case the '3' Id is duplicated.
The query automatically excludes the duplicated items while for me would be important to get them all.
Is there a way to do that directly in SQL?

Comment: What do you mean by get them all? It will return them all even if it excludes the duplicates.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan the title T-SQL suggest SQL Server or Sybase

Comment: Can you split the query with IN (3,4,5,7,8,9) and use UNION ALL to add IN (3)? Can't add full SELECT statements in comments - hope this makes sense. If not let me know.

Comment: I am with Jeff on this. Duplicate values in an `IN` clause will be disregarded in the execution plan but it should match all records whose `Id` is equal to any of the values anyway unless he explicitly adds a `DISTINCT` to his `SELECT`; assuming of course there are duplicate records with the same `Name` value. That's in SQL Server and pretty sure every other database. It's not clear what the problem is here.

Comment: The problem is that I need to get a record (array or whatever) from this SELECT that contains a NAME field for EVERY Id I put into the IN clause. Doesn't matter the Ids are duplicated, I want duplicated NAME to be returned as well. This is not happing in SQL SERVER 2008 R2 because it returns me only the matching NAMEs one time each

Answer (score 3):

The query doesn't exclude duplicates, there just isn't any duplicates to exclude. There is only one record with id 3 in the table, and that is included because there is a 3 in the `in ()` set, but it's not included twice because the 3 exists twice in the set.

To get duplicates you would have to create a table result that has duplicates, and join the table against that. For example:

```
select t.Name
from someTable t
inner join (
  select id = 3 union all
  select 4 union all
  select 5 union all
  select 3 union all
  select 7 union all
  select 8 union all
  select 9
) x on x.id = t.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT Name FROM Tbl 
    JOIN
     (
       SELECT 3 Id UNION ALL
       SELECT 4 Id UNION ALL
       SELECT 5 Id UNION ALL
       SELECT 3 Id UNION ALL
       SELECT 7 Id UNION ALL
       SELECT 8 Id UNION ALL
       SELECT 9 Id
     ) Tmp
     ON tbl.Id = Tmp.Id
```